# Why is Collections.synchronizedList(list) internally using the instanceof check?

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I am checking out the source code for **Collections** class.
I came across the method  **Collections.synchronizedList(list)**

```
public static <T> List<T> synchronizedList(List<T> list) {
    return (list instanceof RandomAccess ?
            new SynchronizedRandomAccessList<>(list) :
            new SynchronizedList<>(list));
}
```

I fail to undestand why are we checking if list is of RandomAccess type.
I understand that ArrayList implements this interface and LinkedList does not.

Also, **SynchronizedRandomAccessList** inherits **SynchronizedList**.
Then what is the point of this check?
Please explain

Comment: String inherits Object ... do you think that means there should be no String class?

Comment: Because if the particular `List` implementation implements the marker interface `RandomAccess`, it should return `SynchronizedRandomAccessList` which is presumably more efficient for list implementations that offer efficient random access; and if the list does not provide random access, then `SynchronizedList` should be used.

Comment: @ Stultuske My question is why are we using the instanceof check

Comment: @RahulMathur the code is quite clear, isn't it? because they want to know whether they should parse the list to one that uses random access, or to one that doesn't

Answer (score 8):

You're almost there. `Collections.synchronizedList(list)` checks for `RandomAccess` because some lists implement `RandomAccess` while others don't.

This `RandomAccess` is a [marker interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern), just like `Serializable`. It tells whether we can randomly access the items in the list. I.e. from an `ArrayList` we can retrieve any item with the same computational costs. On the other hand, we need to walk through a `LinkedList` to get to the nth element.

So, what's happening in `Collections.synchronizedList(list)`? It wraps the `RandomAccess` `List`-s into a `RandomAccess` synchronized list, while it wraps the non-`RandomAccess` lists into a non-`RandomAccess` synchronized lists. Otherwise those lists are identical. Below is the code of `SynchronizedRandomAccessList`. This is a good example for [programming by difference](https://twasink.net/2005/02/07/programming-by-difference/). The two classes are almost identical.

```
static class SynchronizedRandomAccessList<E>
    extends SynchronizedList<E>
    implements RandomAccess {

    SynchronizedRandomAccessList(List<E> list) {
        super(list);
    }

    SynchronizedRandomAccessList(List<E> list, Object mutex) {
        super(list, mutex);
    }

    public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return new SynchronizedRandomAccessList<>(
                list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex), mutex);
        }
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1530674583602358482L;

    /**
     * Allows instances to be deserialized in pre-1.4 JREs (which do
     * not have SynchronizedRandomAccessList).  SynchronizedList has
     * a readResolve method that inverts this transformation upon
     * deserialization.
     */
    private Object writeReplace() {
        return new SynchronizedList<>(list);
    }
}
```

You might ask, what's the point for `RandomAccess` interface? As [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) pointed out, `Collections.binarySearch()` makes decisions based on this interface. Another example is `Collections.reverse()`.

Comment: There are no different locking models. Both use `synchronized`, as the method name suggests and [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) specifies.

Comment: I used non-specific wording. Both classes, `SynchronizedRandomAccessList` and `SynchronizedList` manage the locks differently. This is what I was referring to.

Comment: This is an excellent question to someone expert in this topic :) You see, they are different classes. I *think* there is a good reason behind that. I mean the experts who write the jvm code, they decided to wrap those two kind of lists with different classes.

Answer (score 3):

You have to recall the original purpose of the `RandomAccess` marker interface. If you pass a `List` to another method, it should be able to choose an algorithm suitable for random access or sequential lists. Choosing the right algorithm requires testing for the marker interface via `list instanceof RandomAccess`.

To show [one example](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#210)

```
public static <T>
int binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key) {
    if (list instanceof RandomAccess || list.size()<BINARYSEARCH_THRESHOLD)
        return Collections.indexedBinarySearch(list, key);
    else
        return Collections.iteratorBinarySearch(list, key);
 }
```

(See also [`reverse`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#374), [`shuffle`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#454), [`copy`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#553), and [`fill`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#521))

Now, if you just wrap the list into another object implementing the `List` interface, all such methods see, is the wrapper object, so this information is lost. However, wrappers like the synchronized list do not change the time complexity of random access methods like `get`. Hence, it is desired that if the wrapped list is a random access list, the wrapper should implement `RandomAccess` too, so that methods receiving such a wrapper are still able to detect whether fast random access is available or not.

If you look at the [implementation of `SynchronizedRandomAccessList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#2486), you will see that all it does, is extending `SynchronizedList` and implementing `RandomAccess`, to inherit the behavior and marking itself as having fast random access. The only method it overrides, is `subList`, for exactly the same reason. If the list has efficient random access, its sub lists have as well, so they should implement `RandomAccess` too.

```
static class SynchronizedRandomAccessList<E>
    extends SynchronizedList<E>
    implements RandomAccess {

    SynchronizedRandomAccessList(List<E> list) {
        super(list);
    }

    SynchronizedRandomAccessList(List<E> list, Object mutex) {
        super(list, mutex);
    }

    public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return new SynchronizedRandomAccessList<>(
                list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex), mutex);
        }
    }
```

Note that other wrapper factories like `checkedList` follow the same pattern. So this even works when combining the factories:

```
System.out.println(
    Collections.synchronizedList(Collections.checkedList(new ArrayList<>(), String.class))
    instanceof RandomAccess);
```

→ true

```
System.out.println(
    Collections.synchronizedList(Collections.checkedList(new LinkedList<>(), String.class))
    instanceof RandomAccess);
```

→ false

Comment: basically a way to distinguish and as such to choose the better approach?

Comment: @Eugene: yes. If this was considered right from the start, i.e. in Java 1.2, then it probably resulted in a method `List.isRandomAccess()` that could be simply implemented by delegating to the source list. Unfortunately, this issue was overlooked and the `RandomAccess` marker interface was added in 1.4 (had it been added in 1.8, a `default` method was an option).

Comment: Seems like I never question anything hard enough after reading your answers. Thank u